Flutter Blue Plus's connected System Devices Does Not Work
Connected System Devices in FlutterBluePlus do not work on some Android devices. We are using version 1.14.24 of FlutterBluePlus and have tested it on Android versions 10 ~ 14.
I wrote this code
When I tested it with the same Android device and version, some instances worked while others did not. The results were the same when we tested with the latest version of FlutterBluePlus.
AndroidManifest
I was wondering if there is an issue with FlutterBluePlus at the moment or is it a matter of code writing
